# Unable to use python.sty package

Tags: windows, linux, kile, scripts, python

When compiling a `.tex` file that uses `python.sty` package and contains:

```
\begin{python}
    ...
\end{python}
```

I keep getting an error:

> `./main.tex:33:I can't find file 'bin/main.py.out' \end{python}`
>
> `./main.tex:33:Emergency stop \end{python}`

This happens both when compiling with `PDFLaTeX` or only `LaTeX`. What I tried is:

- ensure `-shell-enable` is on (or `-enable-write18` on Windows),
- find another copy of `python.sty` in case my version was invalid,
- try on Windows 7 and on Debian 6 with Kile
- copy & paste latex samples using `python.sty` from the web

None of the above helps in getting rid of that error. It fails even with extremely simple python code within the `python` environment like: `print "a"`. If also fails when I leave the environment contents empty, but with a different error. It doesn't fail if there are no `python` environments in the document and there is only `\usepackage{python}` at the top. My `python.sty` copy is taken from [here](https://github.com/silky/latex/tree/master/packages/python). Simple example code I tried to compile is there as well.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where can one obtain a LaTeX package named `python`? It doesn't seem to be available through the CTAN.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not available through CTAN. You can get some backup copies, i.e. https://github.com/silky/latex/tree/master/packages/python. It's supposed to be used to embed python code in latex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is definition of `python` environment inspired by `python.sty` package, but rewritten to work on my Windows system. Basically, it takes content from between `\begin{python}` and `\end{python}`, writes it to a file, executes the file as python script and inserts output into the LaTeX document. Full code:

```
\usepackage{verbatim}

\makeatletter
\newwrite\Code@out

\newcommand\python{\obeylines\expandafter\pythonArg\noexpand}

\newcommand\pythonArg[1][tmp.py.in]{%
    \gdef\FNameIn{#1}
    \gdef\FNameOut{tmp.py.out}
    \begingroup
        \@bsphack%
        \immediate\openout\Code@out\FNameIn%
        \let\do\@makeother\dospecials%
        \catcode`\^^M\active%
        \def\verbatim@processline{%
            \immediate\write\Code@out{\the\verbatim@line}}%
        \verbatim@start}

\def\endpython{%
        \immediate\closeout\Code@out\@esphack
    \endgroup

     %Execute python script. Python directory must be in PATH.
     \immediate\write18{python \FNameIn > \FNameOut}
     \input{\FNameOut}
}

\makeatother
```

Comment: When I use this file as a package, I get an error message when I do `\begin{python}` ... `\end{python}` saying: `Paragraph ended before \verbatim@ was complete.`.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine here.  Below is the output from the example included in the README file.  I did remove the `bin/` directory so that I would not need to create that folder.  Perhaps you could try that as well.   Alternatively, try creating a "bin/" directory where your LaTeX file is.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking time to investigate it. It didn't fix the issue, though. Did it create a `main.py.out` file anywhere for you?

Comment: I had saved the sample as README.tex (and edited it to remove the non-LaTeX content) and it created various README... files in the same directory where the .tex file was located including README.py.out.   If you are on Windows, I know that there are sometimes problems with default path to find Python.  Perhaps you can investigate this...  I might be able to find some links for you to look at if you don't know what I mean.

Comment: If you mean adding python's directory to PATH environment variable - it's already done.

Comment: Perhaps try also adding PYTHONPATH as an environment variable ... and perhaps "." as another path variable...

Comment: I'm only wondering what directories should be included in PYTHONPATH then. Location of the .tex file? May I ask what python version and architecture are you running?

Comment: PYTHONPATH should simply include the path to your Python executable.  If I recall correctly from when I was using Windows, and I might be wrong ..., PATH is used from within the console but, if you call Python from some other shell escape command, you need to have PYTHONPATH set up properly (i.e. pointing to Python executable ... no need for anything else afaik).   I currently use Python 2.7 on Mac OSX 2.6.8.