# Embedding Python in LaTeX - Hello example?

Tags: xetex, python

I [found example](http://www.texample.net/weblog/2008/oct/24/embedding-python-latex/) of the using Python in LaTex,  but unfortunately I have problem with it.

- Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
- This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9 32 bit)
- Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AM
  D64)] on win32

MNWE: (xetex --enable-write18 hello.tex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\begin{document}

Say hello Python:

\begin{python}%
print r"Hello \LaTeX!"
\end{python}%
\end{document}
```

Latex Error: I can't find hello.py.out!

But two files (hello.py, latex.py) was generated. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Remove the comment character `%` after `\begin{python}`

Comment: The original `python.sty` doesn't work with Windows.  You might try a modified version (such as [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51376/10742)).  Or if you want the additional features, you might consider [`pythontex`](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The code compiles fine if I remove the `%` characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\begin{document}

Say hello Python:

\begin{python}
print r"Hello \LaTeX!"
\end{python}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that `\begin{python}` needs to see an end-of-line to start it working; and if you comment it, the next one that's seen is too late and the `print` line is gobbled, so nothing is written out.

Comment: I still have same problem. Removing % characters haven't any effect. (error: I can't find hello.py.out!). It makes me sad.

Comment: @jafan Sorry, but I don't know what to say, apart from “install Linux”. ;-)